# Why does the requests library omit the contents of a div element while fetching this page?

Tags: html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a webpage to retrieve a piece of information I found using inspect element.
A search results page contains the following div:

```
<div id="se-search-serp">
...
</div>
```

Using inspect element, I can find the desired tags inside this element:

```
<div class="sc-fznyAO kChtze">
<div data-area="main" class="sc-fznKkj sc-pcxhi kVWWZA">
<h1 class="sc-qXFOy hZbUVv automation-total-books-found">500 results in Books</h1>
<div class="sc-pQfvp hBInHv">
<div class="sc-qXHHN kITAEN"><ul id="search-results-tabs" role="tablist" data-test="tabs" class="sc-pAyMl frsGKv">
<li role="presentation">
<a role="tab" id="search-results-tabs_tabheader_0" data-test="search-results-tabs_tabheader_0" href="#search-results-tabs_tabpanel_0" data-index="0" tabindex="-1" class="sc-pITNg jukMUo">All Matches</a></li>
...
```

I would like to access this content through the Python Requests library. However, when I request the page and print out the text, the contents of this div are missing. Here's the string of relevant text in the very long output:

```
... 
<div id="se-search-serp"></div>
...
```

I have checked that this is the div that contained the content in expect element. It has the same place in the hierarchy and no other divs of the same id exist on the page.

What is going on here? I've observed that many of the tags within `<div id="se-search-serp">` belong to classes with illegible names ("sc-fznyAO","sc-qXFOy", etc.)like the ones shown above. I cannot find any tags like these in the printed page text, although they do show in inspect element. Could this be relevant?

And finally, is there any way to access this content through the requests library?

Edit: The site url I am using is: https://www.chegg.com/search/the%20art%20of%20electronics/#p=1

Comment: The data is probably loaded from external URL via JavaScript. Can you share the URL?

Comment: If the DOM is rendered dynamically with Javascript, requests might not get it, so you would need to scrape it with Selenium